# MetaMask not showing ERC-20 amount in Transaction - Only showing ETH gas fee

Tags: solidity, erc-20, metamask, react, transferfrom

Im experimenting with sending my custom ERC-20 token with MetaMask to my contract.

Im using react.js for a simple front end. I press a button which creates a transaction from my metamask account for a value that I have entered. When the transaction pops up, only the ETH gas fee is shown.

For example, my token is called CHIPS.

I want the transaction to say Total: 10 CHIPS + 0.00237 ETH. I have seen it before but it doesn't do it anymore. The CHIPS do leave my wallet, i.e. the transfer is successful, but I don't see it in the transaction.

I think it may have something to do with my use of the TransferFrom function but I'm not sure. I have one contract calling the ERC-20 contract to make the transfer.

Code:

solidity:

```
function submitBid(uint _bid) public {
token.transferFrom(msg.sender, address(this), _bid); 
}
```

react:

```
enterBid = async() => {
    const fullBid = this.state.bid * 1000000000000000000;
    await this.ForwardAuctionInstance.methods.submitBid(fullBid.toString()).send({from: this.accounts[0]});
    this.getCurrentHighestBid();
    
  }
```